# ReactJS website issue in Safari when opening for first time

Tags: reactjs

When I am opening the ReactJS website in Safari when opening for first time. Same issue happening in firefox. Working fine on the chrome.

[image]

Comment: share the code which you think might be causing the issue.

Comment: hello can you share some images or code because it's not clear about the issue. I have once faced this type of issue please check in your code if you use any regular expression. because some regular expressions do not work in Safari.